# tflint fails when calling terraform `filebase64sha256()` on a variable

Tags: terraform

I have a terraform module for an AWS lambda function that looks something like below:

```hcl
module "my-lambda-function" {
  ...
  source_code_path = local.filename
  source_code_hash = filebase64sha256(local.filename)
  ...
}
```

The syntax is alright, but I have an issue when running tflint where tflint evaluates all the variables and attempts to call `filebase64sha256()` on the non-existent `local.filename` (because terraform apply is yet to be executed) to generate the resource's `source_code_hash`.

Is there a way to prevent this kind of evaluation? I would like to lint the module though, but it looks like a bug when a linter calls functions to operate on defined resources, rather than actual resources.

Answer (score 0):

Worked around this thus:

```hcl
  source_code_hash = fileexists(local.filename) ? filebase64sha256(local.filename) : null
```